# How can i set tiny_mce content with c sharp

Tags: c#, tinymce

I have a textarea tiny_mce such as

```
<textarea id="Textarea1"  name="abc" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%">

            </textarea>
```

I want to set it in page load.
If i add runat server , this change to "pure textarea" that is not tiny_mce control.
How can i set content from c sharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that TinyMCE is a JavaScript-based editor that runs 100% in the client - there are no server side APIs to talk to TinyMCE.

The API to load content is a JavaScript API that runs in the browser:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#setcontent

If you want to use this API you need to pass the data from the server to the browser and then call `setContent()` with that data.  You can throw the data into a JavaScript variable, make an AJAX call to fetch the data as the page loads - you have several choices.

If you want to do this server side the only option is to place the HTML inside the `<textarea>` tag.  Something like:

```
<textarea>
    &lt;p&gt;text &amp;lt; text&lt;/p&gt;
</textarea>
```

A major complication with this approach is that the HTML you place in the `<textarea>` needs to be escaped as in my example above.  This is not a requirement when using the `setContent()` API.

**UPDATE:**  If refreshing sometimes make this work you likely have a timing issue - you are likely trying to use TinyMCE APIs before the editor is initialized.  If your goal is to load content when TinyMCE is loaded you can use something like this in the TinyMCE configuration:

```
setup: function (editor) {
  editor.on('init', function () {
      // Your AJAX call to get the content
      this.setContent(variableWithTheContent);
  });
}
```

This function will not get called before the editor is initialized so you can be sure that APIs like `setContent()` will work at that point.

Comment: thanks very much .
But when i use ajax , and write
 "      success: function (data) {
                items = data.split(":;:");
                alert(items[0]);
activeEditor.setContent(items[0]);"
it is ok , but when i clear
 "alert(items[0]); "
it does not show anything ??

Comment: Are you sure TinyMCE has completed its initialization?  Do you actually have an "active" editor?  The `alert()` causes you to click something and by the time you do that the editor is finished loading.  Also note that `activeEditor` is only true once you interact with the editor - you can use `tinymce.get()` to locate an editor by the ID of its underlying `<textarea>`

Comment: Tinymce some times do and some times do not load.

Comment: I use                 
tinyMce.get('Textarea1').setContent(items[0]);
but does not work.

Comment: Is the issue that the method call fails or that there is no data loaded?  Are there errors in the JavaScript console?  What happens if you load a hard coded text string?

Comment: If i hold "control" key and many time click in "F5" it works.